# Flutter Login to Post APIs Graphql Onlone

Tags: flutter, authentication, graphql

I create a flutter login project with graphql APIs online, but is not working...
i need you help guys

1. Set the domain variable:

   ```
   final String domain = 'http://167.172.89.12:8082';
   ```
2. Define the login URL:

   ```
   final String loginUrl = '$domain/auth';
   ```
3. Here's an updated example of the Flutter login screen using the modified variables:

   ```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

   class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
   }

   class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
     final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
     final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

     Future<void> _login() async {
       try {
         final dio = Dio();
         final response = await dio.post(
           loginUrl,
           data: {
             'email': _emailController.text,
             'password': _passwordController.text,
           },
           options: Options(contentType: 'application/json'),
         );

         if (response.statusCode == 200) {
           final data = response.data;
           // Process the login response data here
         } else {
           // Handle error response
         }
       } catch (error) {
         // Handle Dio errors
       }
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text('Login'),
         ),
         body: Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
           child: Column(
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
             children: [
               TextField(
                 controller: _emailController,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                   labelText: 'Email',
                 ),
               ),
               SizedBox(height: 16.0),
               TextField(
                 controller: _passwordController,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                   labelText: 'Password',
                 ),
                 obscureText: true,
               ),
               SizedBox(height: 32.0),
               ElevatedButton(
                 onPressed: _login,
                 child: Text('Login'),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
   }
   ```

I create a flutter login project with graphql APIs online, but is not working...
i need you help guys please..